# Wordpress Url Rewriting using function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to change the dynamic urls to static. But don't know how to optimize this url:
http://domain.com/advanced-search/?filter_search_action%5B%5D=sales&filter_search_type%5B%5D=apartments&advanced_city=jersey-city&advanced_area=bayonne&min-bedrooms=&available-from=&price_low=0&price_max=1500000&submit=SEARCH+PROPERTIES

As i want something like:
http://domain.com/sales/apartments/jersey-city/bayonne///0/1500000/SEARCH+PROPERTIES.html

Even i have tried using function.php

```
function add_query_vars($new_var) {
$new_var[] = "?filter_search_action%5B%5D";
$new_var[] = "filter_search_type%5B%5D";
$new_var[] = "advanced_city";
$new_var[] = "advanced_area";
$new_var[] = "advanced_rooms";
$new_var[] = "advanced_bath";
$new_var[] = "price_low";
$new_var[] = "price_max";
$new_var[] = "submit";

return $new_var;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
$new_rules = array('([^/]+)' => 'index.php/advanced-search/?filter_search_action%5B%5D=$matches[1]&filter_search_type%5B%5D=$matches[2]&advanced_city=$matches[3]&advanced_area=$matches[4]&advanced_rooms=$matches[5]&advanced_bath=$matches[6]&price_low=$matches[7]&price_max=$matches[8]&submit=$matches[9]');
    $rules = $new_rules + $rules;
    return $rules;
    }

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Unfortunately its not working. Need your help friends...Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: You've got so many problems here, I don't know where to start. Read the [Custom Templates section of the Rewrite API documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Using_Custom_Templates_with_custom_querystring) first, and rewrite your code to those examples. You've got the added complication that `filter_search_type` and `filter_search_action` could have multiple variables each (`%5B%5D` => `[]`).